Как перевести текст на новую строку?
@router.callback_query(F.data == 'Zayvka')
async def Manual(callback: CallbackQuery):
    await callback.message.answer('Сколько готовы уделять времени?'
                                  '2.Есть ли у вас бюджет?')

как сделать чтоб приходил сообщение вот так:
1.Сколько готовы уделять времени?
2.Есть ли у вас бюджет

а не 1.Сколько готовы уделять времени?2.Есть ли у вас бюджет

\n поставить?..

Так, как вы написали в коде сейчас - это способ просто "сцепить" две строки, как будто они идут подряд.

@router.callback_query(F.data == 'Zayvka')
async def Manual(callback: CallbackQuery):
    await callback.message.answer('1. Сколько готовы уделять времени?\n2. Есть ли у вас бюджет?')

Наверное можно было бы спросить и в прошлой вашей теме
